# Android doesn't keep static field in activity after app goes to background

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm building an android app.
I created a "BaseActivity" class which holds a static field with my User, all other activities extend "BaseActivity".

during the `Application onCreate()` i do:

```
BaseActivity.initializeUser();
```

which basically instantiate the User for the app, this way after that all my activities have access to the user.

I ABSOLUTELY GUARANTEE THAT NOWHERE IN THE CODE USER IS SET TO NULL

THE PROBLEM IS: Sometimes, when people are using the app normally (production) sometimes after a while they get `nullpointerexception` because the activity tries to access some field in User and it was null

according to crashlytics this always happen during some activity `oncreate` (none specifical, can be any)

WHY???

is android dropping  my singleton objects to save memory? if so why many other libraries like Firebase, Admob and others they have a similar initialization method that is called during Application onCreate() but after that they stay fine in the app no matter what?

**====== UPDATE =========**

The `initializeUser` is like:

```
 private static void initializeUser(){
        
        currentUser = new User();
        //then i do update the user's fields
        currentUser.setLocation(something); 
        currentUser.setRef(something);
        currentUser.setVersion(something);
        //these values are read from various places but all methods are SYNCHRONOUS and run on main thread
        
    }

currentUser is `private` and `static` and this method is the UNIQUE line of code that does an attribution to this field.
```

and yet, users get nullpointerexception while invoking some methods from this entity...

Comment: What is the implementation of `initializeUser()`? For example, does it do asynchronous work? If so, perhaps that work is not yet completed by the time your activity attempts to reference the `User`. "is android dropping my singleton objects to save memory?" -- generally, no, but it would depend a bit on your implementation (e.g., using `SoftReference`).

Comment: @CommonsWare, I added extra info. All of this can "easily" be solved by adding ´if(currentuser==null)´ during ´onCreate()´ of BaseActivity, but this approach really annoys me because there should be a single entry point to the Application itself in where i would initialize all basic fields and sdk

Comment: If you were crashing elsewhere, it might be [due to the backup agent](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ov18d2/this_is_why_your_subclassed_application_isnt/). I don't know how that would affect an activity, though. 

Comment: Please post the code from `Application.onCreate()`.